# How do I save label images from pydrake / Drake directly to disk?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, python-imaging-library, drake

How do I write label images from Drake to disk using `PIL`?

If I try `Image.fromarray(label)`, I get an error that looks like this:

```
  File ".../PIL/Image.py", line 2751, in fromarray
    raise TypeError("Cannot handle this data type: %s, %s" % typekey) from e
TypeError: Cannot handle this data type: (1, 1, 1), <i2
```

Answer (score 1):

Some image libraries, like `PIL`, OpenCV, etc., may require you to reshape your input and cast to a specific `dtype`.

Let's say you get your label image from the following notebook: 
[`drake/tutorials/rendering_multibody_plant.ipynb`](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/6d52545e1517ff884ea5561e054706f46364e108/tutorials/rendering_multibody_plant.ipynb#Render-color-and-label-images-using-matplotlib)

```py
label = sensor.label_image_output_port().Eval(sensor_context).data
```

#### Option 1.a: PIL

For `PIL` (at least what's available on Ubuntu 18.04), you can use `np.int32`. 
Example:

```py
from PIL import Image

img = label.squeeze(-1).astype(np.int32)
file = "/tmp/test.png"
Image.fromarray(img).save(file)
img_2 = np.asarray(Image.open(file))
label_2 = np.expand_dims(img_2.astype(np.int16), axis=-1)

# This should print 0, showing that you get the same image out.
print(np.max(label - label_2))
```

See: https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/2970

#### Option 1.b: OpenCV

For OpenCV (3.4.0), you can use `np.uint16`, in addition to `IMREAD_UNCHANGED`:

```
import cv2

img = label.squeeze(-1).astype(np.uint16)
file = "/tmp/test.png"
cv2.imwrite(file, img)
img_2 = cv2.imread(file, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
label_2 = np.expand_dims(img_2.astype(np.int16), axis=-1)

# This should print 0, showing that you get the same image out.
print(np.max(label - label_2))
```

See: http://jamesgregson.ca/16-bit-image-io-with-python.html

Example screen capture of the notebook: \

> [image]

### Option 2: Use `*.npy` or `*.pkl`

If you're just loading / saving for Python itself, you can just use [`np.save`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) or [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html).

Comment: For reference, see C++ code for using VTK: [image_writer.cc](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/6d52545e1517ff884ea5561e054706f46364e108/systems/sensors/image_writer.cc#L24)